# Newbie Error Apple Mach-O Linker Error

Tags: c++, iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm fairly new here, but I'm having a Apple Mach-O Linker Error:[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJbbZ.png)

This is my app delegate!
    //
    //  AppDelegate.m
    //  VCContainmentTut
    //
    //  Created by A Khan on 01/05/2013.
    //  Copyright (c) 2013 AK. All rights reserved.
    //

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "RootController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "VidViewController.h"
#import "SelectVideo1.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    VidViewController *vidViewController = [[VidViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vidViewController];
[self.window setRootViewController:navController1];

    SelectVideo1 *selectVideo1 = [[SelectVideo1 alloc] initWith:@"Movie Trailers"];
    //[self.navController pushViewController:selectVideo1 animated:YES];


    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    UIStoryboard *tabStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"TabStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UIStoryboard *navStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"NavStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navController = [navStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Nav Controller"];
    UITabBarController *tabController = [tabStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Tab Controller"];
    ViewController *redVC, *greenVC;
    redVC = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    greenVC = [[ViewController alloc] init];

    redVC.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    greenVC.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    RootController *menuController = [[RootController alloc]
                                      initWithViewControllers:@[tabController, redVC, greenVC, navController, selectVideo1]
                                      andMenuTitles:@[@"Cheats", @"Videos", @"WalkThroughs", @"Nav"]];
    self.window.rootViewController = menuController;
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}



@end
```

Comment: Did you add Framework MediaPlayer.framework to the project?

Comment: Ah after adding that, 3 errors were removed. However a few other remain. Such as:

     "_SecCertificateCopyData", referenced from:
      -[AFURLConnectionOperation connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:] in AFURLConnectionOperation.o

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/sQK1Js5.png

Comment: ah, i needed to add security.framework!

Answer (score 0):

Your errors are caused by you trying to use code that you haven't told the project (so the linker) exists. You need to add the dependencies to the project. In this case, the frameworks defining the features you're trying to use.